# How does a bad spell (Tantra or Maran Vidhya) work?

Tags: tantra

There is one type of sadhu called [Aghori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aghori), which also has one sub-type called [Kapalik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kapalika).

While reading a book on [Pujya Mota](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pujya_Mota), I found that a Kapalik used a bad spell on Pujya Mota to make him, his Sishya (student). I also found similar stories in other books and came across people who believe in these spells. So how do these spells actually work? How it possible that one just speaks a tantrik mantra and it hurts others?

Comment: Kind of similar to question asked in http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3975/how-does-a-boon-or-curse-work

Answer (score 5):

First of all it should be noted that Tantra is not a synonym for "bad spells". It is a agamic tradition of worship. Power can be used in a positive or a negative way.

Marana comes under the "shat-karmas" of tantra. Here the will-power and power generated from the sadhana is used and directed against an individual. With the help of yantra, mantras, and other methods the energy is directed against the individual which can cause him grave diseases/paralysis or death. But such acts are extremely difficult to perform. It is only to be done when there is a great danger of life from the opposite person or any problem of similar magnitude. There are heavy prayashchita to be done if someone does the prayoga for extreme reasons.

Answer (score 4):

It is a myth about Aghor sampradaya/sect.
Aghora was a great yogi and he never endorsed any of the Maran Vidya n all.
Kapalik is a sect which worships Tamas attributes of Shiva and they do not relate to Aghora sect.

The Maran Vidya was brought in to use by some sick people which has nothing to do with Vaidik Dharma.

I read in a book on Adi Shankaracharya that Maran vidya was used against him. 
In Maran a goat is prepared for slaughtering its neck as a symbol of the person under target and some 'tamas mantras' are used.

It comes in shivageeta that the one who performs Jaran, Maran or Vashikaran goes to hell for ages.

Answer (score 0):

*Shatkarmas* are *six karmas* in Tantra that are used for a certain degree of manipulation of the physical realm out of material benefit. During the Old Ages, the fights between the armies extensively used certain aspects of tantric practices to have an edge over the war. Such acts include - hiding certain Yantras or materials (such as stone) that would divide the enemy crews or kill them so as to get an edge over them in the war. One such good example of such Tantric yogi was *Chanakya* from historical evidence.

Now the methods of *shatkarmas* would vary from situation to situation, only an experienced yogi is able to construct these certain mantras in that specific situation so that he/she could bring it to full success.

The principle of Tantra, we are concerned with two aspects :- *shiva* and *shakti*. The mechanical object into consideration is roughly called *shiva* and the energy that operates on the mechanical object is usually referred to as *shakti*. In this route of the philosophy - we seek to control the *shakti* (or energy aspect that is influenced by the flow of the time) through manipulation of shiva (materialistic aspects using tools like - materials, yantras, mudras, mantras, etc.), *Marana* is one of them (death).

There are various ways to plan a *shatkarmas* such as:

### 1. Yoga

Those proficient in the art of yoga and *major* and *minor* siddhis are capable of invoking it to influence the death of people to certain degrees. According to the principles of Advaita - the whole universe (brahman) is composed of self (like a dream is a state of mind), hence the true self is beyond this universe (which is similar to a dream-like state in that sense), and through meditation is capable to get a control like that.

Certain Yogis have the ability to come out of their physical body and influence them, they can use other eternal entities that might be interpreted as ghosts, or spirits by ordinary men for their purpose too.

### 2. Mantras/Yantras/Tantra

In Tantra, certain body parts are reflections of the parts (or objects) of the Brahman (absolute reality). They use these parts (called Nadis) to get siddhis. The points where Nadis are branched are called *Chakras* (or flowers as chakras and petals as emerging Nadis from that chakra). Certain Nadis and Chakras are associated with certain siddhis that are easier to get than Yogic methods, for example - Mooldhara Chakra and Ajna Chakras are associated with the siddhis to get the knowledge of past, present, and future, Hrit Chakra (not to be confused with Anahata Chakra!) is associated with the ability to control people emotionally.

Mantras and Yantras are shortcuts to activate them and obtain their siddhis. Mantras are obtained via the extensive practice of Laya Yoga and trial and error. For each given situation, the planning and the mantras might differ. There's no general mantra for all.

### Astrological Methods

In astrology, there are materialistic rituals (or sometimes mantras too) that are devoted to shifting astral planets (NOT physical ones!) to change the influence of someone's life. These rituals include using certain stones, gravels, yantras, mantras, etc could also be used to perform shatkarmas in opposite ways.

---

It is important to note that methods might differ depending on the practice to style of the yogi. They are non-exhaustive. The siddhis, knowledge, and yoga associated with such practices might develop over multiple decades of the time. They should be seen with the intent of distraction. The real purpose of the tools listed above is clear in the Upanishads - to get the knowledge of the infinite cosmos which is liberation.

**It is possible that a person who spent years of practices on such practices to NOT be enlightened (jivanmukta) and might not get liberation will surely get bounded by Karmic reactions after such low performances, while the victim who strives liberation might break the laws of karma (jivanmukta) who would get liberated and all of such performances to get nullified for him with absolutely no effect. Thus, striving for enlightenment is always superior to shatkarmas.**

Answer (score -3):

The person has to be comming up from bhurloka and the evolution of consciousness needs match the way ... lets just bring Rahu into point .... time builds up in the mind as to match the environmental conditioning and lack of grade made to grain of character thats from bon in gain of human life....

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE. Answers on this site should be elaborate enough to solve the questioner's doubts and should contain relevant texts from Hindu scriptures, eg, Vedas, Puranas, Upanishads, etc to support your answer. Please either edit your answer to provide more details or delete/comment instead.

Comment: What does your answer mean? How is is related to maran vidya etc