# How someone know that bad spell is done on him or other person?

Tags: tantra

Consider, that person X due to some reason did bad spell on person Y. How can Y or other person Z can identify that bad spell is happen on Y by X. Specially if X did spell that make Y ill or mentally unbalanced? Is there any way to find?

Please note that this question already assume that black magic is real, you can find various places and resources where existence of black spell is proven.

Comment: Possible duplicate or related: [Black Magic/Kala Jadu/ Pilli Soonyam are real?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11029/black-magic-kala-jadu-pilli-soonyam-are-real). Even though your Q is interesting, it might get an impression of "opinion based" due to its controversial nature. Because, it asks to assume that "Black magic" exists. Some people believe such "bad spell" or "black magic" as `superstition`, hence you may want to retag with that.

Comment: This post can be merged with: [How does a bad spell (Tantra or Maran Vidhya) work?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6745/1049)

Comment: A person who's under a black magic spell is said to exhibit few distinct symptoms.See the following page you will get useful infos.But i'm not quite sure about the authenticity of that page hence did not post an answer based on those infos .http://www.vedanta-occult-spells.com/effects-of-black-magic.html

Comment: @iammilind: I already assume that bad spell is in existence, the second question that you mentioned, How does.... is also also asked by myself, that was about how it work, this question is about the symptoms of bad spell and to find who did this.

Comment: @Rickross: Yes, I see but there the general symptoms, can't able to identify the exact reason.

Comment: @Rickross : There was a talk between me and my friend, at that time he mentioned that his mother has some power, so can she able to identify, if someone curse by bad spell. But when I ask how she able to, then he say, my mother invite god inside of her and then she able to predict. So, clearly this should not be the only way, there has to be some other way also so identify.

Comment: @Kiran We have seven important [chakras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chakra) in our *sookshma* or subtle body. If at least one chakra gets activates, we get supernatural power. Scientific studies proved  there's more grey matter (in Physical or Gross body) at those locations. So, women in south Indian Villages invite Grama Devatas into their body. So, actually what's happening there is for them chakras get activated due to more Bhakti (or whatever you call) and they communicate with Devas. But Karma of a person make this unstable and chakra deactivates we need no Karma to stabilize it. (1/2)

Comment: @Kiran Most of those women fake it. 60% are charlatans, 39% Ghosts and 1% real Devatas. So, can't just run to conclusions. If she (your friend's mother) really invites Gods into her, ask her questions such as "When is Kalki coming?", "Who is Supreme God?", " Ask about your Purva janama?" and all interesting questions. Decide yourself.(2/2)

Comment: @AnilKumar: Yes, but cannot able to ask these questions because they consider me as child in these things and if i try to, even my family going to think that I am ...Atheist.