# Will saying something in anger come true?

Tags: gunas, curse

According to Hinduism, will saying done thing in anger come true.

For example, a father says to his son in a fit of rage, "You will kill me!"

Does Hunduism believe these words will come true?

If so, how to break out of this curse?

Comment: Its the THADHASTHU DEVATAS who approve every of our wishes, desires, curses. So, to answer to your question it is a YES...

Comment: A pious/saintly person's words may come true when told with any emotion (be it aggression or love). This happened when GAndhari cursed Krishna & Krishna cursed Ashwatthama. They may not be angry at that time, as "anger" is considered "disorientation" of mind & the largest obstacle in spiritual path. For commoners, the words came in anger or aggression is mostly like a line drawn on water. They deserve forgiveness.

Comment: If the person who cursed has "tons" of Good karma or virtues (could be acquired by doing *poojas* or *Satvic* helping (without expectation)), then words may come true. But, it depends on good karma and intensity of curse.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does a boon or curse work?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3975/how-does-a-boon-or-curse-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will say No, Everyone's Curse or Blessings is not going to be true. People who have achieved the power to curse & give blessings, their sayings will only be true.

Every Mother wants her son to be a good human or a rich man.  She always give her blessings to her son, but for everyone it doesn't become true.

Every Father blesses her daughter to lead a happy life but those blessings does not become true.

Like that only, Every enemy may curse a person to die in hell, but it is not going to be true because that person has not achieved the power to do so.

**In Anger, Normal People speaks what their inner conscience wants them to tell. So Sometimes the things come true because of coincidence & most of the times, it is expected outcome of a human being, because of series of past events.**

Comment: Pls.add some sources from authentic Hindu Scriptures in your answer to support it.

Answer (score 1):

If the person cursing you is a bad person, then don't worry about it. It is never going to come true. But if he is a pious person, then he himself is the remedy.Such people curse only when very angry. Once they are pacified, approach them with humility and seek forgiveness. They will definitely tell the way to break the curse. No doubt about that.

Comment: You can use edit link to the left of your answer and merge both your answers into one and delete the one you don't need.

Comment: oh good ... because so many bad people cursed me ... I was scared it was coming true in my life .... whew!!!

Answer (score 0):

A curse or a blessing is a 'sankalp' of the person by whom it has been given. Know one thing for fact that 'sankalps' of people afflicted with impure thoughts never come true. Only 'sankalps' of people whose minds have been purified by dharma, tapasya or knowledge of brahma (or ishwar) come true. There is no other way of making a curse or blessing productive except purity of mind (or heart) and that comes from dharma, tapasya or knowledge of brahma.

Comment: Source : If you read parts of purana where brahmagyan is described, you will find explanation. Eg: In Srimad Bhagwad purana, when Sri Sukdev Goswami gives final teachings to Parikshit, he describes how the mind is the cause of creation, continuation or end of a jiva's life. One can also refer to the story of Daityaguru Sukracharya :- how he went to swarga after Suruchi apsara by sankalp of his mind and took many more births after that before eventually returing to his original body. There is a detailed explanation on how the mind is responsible for one's condition, birth and death.

Comment: The puranas also explain the creation of cosmos by God Brahma by 'sankalps' in a step by step process. I will try to explain it in a simple way : Let us consider someone eating food. When his mind creates a 'sankalp' to take the food in hand, then the hand moves to take the food. You see , without first manifesting in mind, no action can be manifested by the body. The 'sankalps' which one is capable to do by body, such 'sankalps' materialise because the body is capable of doing it. But, the case with curses and blessings are different. They are outside the bounds of bodily capabilities.